# How to start IBM Cognos Dashboard Embedded>

Tags: python, dataframe, ibm-cloud, dashboard, cognos

Although I create IBM Cognos Dashboard Embedded, I can't find any associate service to start dashboard.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[IBM Cognos Dashboard Embedded](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/ibm-cognos-dashboard-embedded) is a service which can be used to embed analytic dashboards into other apps. Thus, you have to code up your own "hosting app". See this [GitHub repo with a sample for GitHub traffic analytics](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats) for how to use the code. The related IBM Cloud solution tutorial "[Combining serverless and Cloud Foundry for data retrieval and analytics](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-serverless-github-traffic-analytics)" discusses the code.